# Qt QObject and boost::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, qt, boost, shared-ptr, qobject

I am creating a mixin between two classes using the boost::enable_shared_from_this template. So I am adding a new functionality to this class:

```
class MyOldClass :
        public Connection,
        public boost::enable_shared_from_this<MyOldClass>
{ ... };
```

I did use this before with a normal class (not a QtObject, just a C++ plain class) and everything works.

But now I am doing the same with a QMainWindow and it basically crash:

```
class MainWindow :
        public QMainWindow,
        public Connection,
        public boost::enable_shared_from_this<MainWindow>
{ Q_OBJECT ... };
```

Is it possible that there is any problem doing this with a QObject? Not sure why this is happening.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where does it crash, what exception do you observe, etc?

Comment: Thanks Igor.
The Connection class has a pure virtual method called getSharedPtr(). This method is then implemented in MainWindow just returning shared_from_this() with type boost::shared_ptr<Connection>. 
If I declare a test method on the Connection class which just does: getSharedPtr(); and I call this test method from the MainWindow class, it crash. So the problem seems to be related to retrieve a shared_from_this() pointer from MainWindow.

Comment: @user1963961 Is a `shared_ptr` to the window created anywhere before you call `shared_from_this()`? And anyway, Qt usually has its own ownership scheme (parent owns children), so mixing this with `shared_ptr` ownership scheme will need *very* careful design.

Comment: @Angew No it is called only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you don't create a `shared_ptr` before you call `shared_from_this()`. But that's the problem. `x.shared_from_this()` only works once a `shared_ptr` to `x` exists. If you never create one, you're violating a precondition of `shared_from_this()`, so your program has undefined behaviour.

`shared_from_this()` only serves to retrieve a pointer sharing ownership with existing shared pointers; it cannot be used to create the first one.

Comment: You are right, check my own answer below (I was mixing shared_ptr implementations).

Answer (score 1):

Ok folks, it has been my fault but the answer could help to someone:

1. As Angew said it is necessary to create the first instance of MainWindow using a shared_ptr (I didn't understand your question the first time).
2. I was doing this **but** I was using the std::shared_ptr implementation instead of the boost::shared_ptr one. Mixing both was producing this results.
3. It works now but as Angew said one has to be very careful using shared_ptr's with the Qt ownership scheme.
4. The inheritance order specified in the MainWindow declaration is the only one valid. As Angew said: "When inheriting from QObject or a class derived from it, QObject (or that derived class) must be the first one in the base class list. So that won't work"

Thank you

Comment: I do not see how enable_shared_from_this is going to work for you when inheriting from QObject (or anything else) as well. You should be getting bad_weak_ptr exceptions. That was exactly what I was trying to do when I had to post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131475/shared-from-this-when-inheriting-from-class-defined-by-third-party