# shared_from_this when inheriting from class defined by third party

Tags: c++

I've read many posts on stack-overflow about shared_from_this, bad_weak_ptr exceptions, and multiple inheritance while trying to research my problem. All of them propose you inherit a base class from enable_shared_from_this, and then derive from that. Well, what does one do when the class you have to derive from is a coming from a third party library that you cannot edit?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class ThirdPartyClass
{
public:
    ThirdPartyClass() {}
    ThirdPartyClass(const ThirdPartyClass &) = delete;
    virtual ~ThirdPartyClass() {};
};

class A : public ThirdPartyClass, std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    A():ThirdPartyClass(){}
    virtual ~A(){}

    void Foo();
};

void DoStuff(std::shared_ptr<A> ptr)
{
    std::cout << "Good job if you made it this far!" << std::endl;
}

void A::Foo()
{
    DoStuff(shared_from_this());    // throws here
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
    a->Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You wrap this class in your own class and add `using` directives to forward relevant methods from it

Comment: The other issues you read about are most likely all about cases where someone wanted multiple `shared_from_this<T>` base classes in a single class hierarchy tree. That's not the issue here. (The actual unrelated mistake is already answered.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you are not public inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this` and `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` [cannot detect](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this#Notes) that the object requires such support. Not because of inheritance from third party class.

So, to fix just inherit as public:

```
class A : public ThirdPartyClass, public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
```